# How association mapping Many-To-One or two using doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities, `Student` and `Responsible` (father/mother or tutors). I have to keep both information in the database, so I have to relate both. I think that the best way would be an association `Many-To-One` adding a foreign key of each responsible (two maximum) in the `Student` table. I do not know if this would be possible with this association or whether it would be necessary to make a one `Many-To-Many` association.

```
 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

 class Student{
  ....
 /** 
  *@ORM\ManyToOne(targerEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible") 
  *@ORM\JoinColumn(name="responsible_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  protected $responsible;
 }
```

I'm a bit new to the topic, I appreciate any help possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Change to Many-To-Many

I would change to `Many-To-Many` This means one `Responsible` can be responsible for several students (a collection of `Student`) and a student can have many responsibles (a collection of `Responsible`):

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Responsible
{
    /** 
     *@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\Student", mappedBy="responsibles")
     */
    private $students;

    /**
     * It is important to initialize your $students collection
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $students = new ArrayCollection
    }

    // ALL STUDENT SETTERS + GETTERS
    /**
     * Get students
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getStudents()
    {
        return $this->students;
    }

    /**
     * Add student.
     *
     * @param Student $student
     * @return self
     */
    public function addStudent(Student $student)
    {
        $this->students[] = $student;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add students.
     *
     * @param Collection $students
     * @return self
     */
    public function addStudents(Collection $students)
    {
        foreach ($students as $student) {
            $this->addStudent($student);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove student.
     *
     * @param Student $student
     */
    public function removeStudent(Student $student)
    {
        $this->students->removeElement($student);
    }

    /**
     * Remove students.
     *
     * @param Collection $students
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeStudents(Collection $students)
    {
        foreach ($students as $student) {
            $this->removeStudent($student);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

In your `Student`:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Student
{
    /** 
     *@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible", mappedBy="student")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="student_responisble",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="student_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="responsible_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    private $responsibles;

    /**
     * It is important to initialize your $responsibles collection
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $responsibles = new ArrayCollection
    }

    // ALL RESPONSIBLE SETTERS + GETTERS
    /**
     * Get responsibles
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getResponsibles()
    {
        return $this->responsibles;
    }

    /**
     * Add responsible.
     *
     * @param Responsible $responsible
     * @return self
     */
    public function addResponsible(Responsible $responsible)
    {
        $this->responsibles[] = $responsible;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add responsibles.
     *
     * @param Collection $responsibles
     * @return self
     */
    public function addResponsibles(Collection $responsibles)
    {
        foreach ($responsibles as $responsible) {
            $this->addResponsible($responsible);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove responsible.
     *
     * @param Responsible $responsible
     */
    public function removeResponsible(Responsible $responsible)
    {
        $this->responsibles->removeElement($responsible);
    }

    /**
     * Remove responsibles.
     *
     * @param Collection $responsibles
     * @return self
     */
    public function removeResponsibles(Collection $responsibles)
    {
        foreach ($responsibles as $responsible) {
            $this->removeResponsible($responsible);
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

---

### Alternative solution

If you really want to restrict the amount of responsibles for one student then you could also add the two responsible persons directly to student as `$firstResponsible` and `$secondResponsible` and add a custom `getResponsibles` method so you can get them all at once in an array. You can later also add a `$thirdResponsible` if necessary of course.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Student
{   
    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targerEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="first_responsible_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $firstResponsible;

    /** 
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targerEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible") 
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="second_responsible_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $secondResponsible;

    /**
     * Set first responsible
     *
     * @param Responsible $responsible
     * @return self
     */
    public function setFirstResponsible(Responsible $responsible)
    {
        $this->firstResponsible = $responsible;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get first responsible
     *
     * @return Responsible
     */
    public function getFirstResponsible()
    {
        return $this->firstResponsible;
    }

    /**
     * Set second responsible
     *
     * @param Responsible $responsible
     * @return self
     */
    public function setSecondResponsible(Responsible $responsible)
    {
        $this->secondResponsible = $responsible;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get second responsible
     *
     * @return Responsible
     */
    public function getSecondResponsible()
    {
        return $this->secondResponsible;
    }

    /**
     * Get student responsibles
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getResponsibles()
    {
        $responsibles = array();

        if(isset($this->firstResponsible)){
            $responsibles[] = $this->firstResponsible;
        }

        if(isset($this->secondResponsible)){
            $responsibles[] = $this->secondResponsible;
        }
        return $responsibles;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you for all the help @Wilt. I think the second option is the one I was talking about. My first thought was to add to the `Student` table a foreign key for each responsible (id of the `Responsible` table ). And in the `Responsible` table  all those responsible with complete information differentiated by id, for when you need some information responsible for any student. Is that the same idea as you have told me the second choice? And if so, as I have setters and getters of the properties `$first` and `$second` not need the `getResponsibles` method which you tells me right?

Comment: @Joseph Yes I think this is similar to what you thought. I added setters and getters for first and second responsible so it is more clear.

Comment: Thank you again @Wilt. One last question I have about the code added by you, What are the labels `@param` and `@return` use for? Excuse me if it's something basic, I'm starting.

Comment: These [@annotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annotation) are used for documenting the code. It is called php-doc or php documentation. You can read more on this standard for documenting php code [here](http://www.phpdoc.org/). You don't need this.

Comment: @joseph We can remove some of our comments here since they won't be useful to other users...

Answer (score 1):

Well, a student can have more than one Responsible (tutor, father or mother) and it's presumably possible that a tutor could be mentoring more than one student, or a parent might have more than one child who is a student.

So a many to many relationship would work best here. Even if you have a limit of two Responsible entities, there's still a many to many requirement based on the information you've given.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible as it's not complicated case.

You can use `ManyToMany` association if one `Responsible` can have more than one Student else it's enough to use bidirectional `ManyToOne` association in your `Student` entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Student
{
    /** 
     *@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible", inversedBy="student")
     */
    private $responsible;
}
```

and your `Responsible` entity should be:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Responsible
{
    /** 
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="myBundle\Entity\Responsible", mappedBy="responsible")
     */
    private $student;
}
```

`JoinColumn` is not necessary if you want to use standard naming for your fields: `field_id`.

Also you should use `private` properties if you do not plan to inherit from your entities.

Please read well written official `Symfony` [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and `Doctrine` [documentation](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) for more information about the topic.